# Duda con consulta en Mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo una consulta con el resultado de ventas de productos, una columna con los totales, pero no soy capaz de que muestre el nombre de los productos (que están en otra tabla).

Copio la consulta del resultado:

```
select 
    total 
from (
    select 
        sum(cuantia) as total 
    from pedidos 
    group by ref_producto
) as suma 
where total < 5;
```

Ahora necesito saber el nombre de los productos que los tengo en otra tabla. Son 30 resultados los que me da la consulta que he copiado, por lo tanto necesito sus respectivos nombres.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Para poder ayudarte mejor, necesitas poner más datos de tus tablas (sus columnas y tipos de datos). Seguramente necesitas un JOIN a tu tabla de productos y preferentemente cambiar tu consulta para usar HAVING en vez de WHERE con una subconsulta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo que estás buscando, y como bien te indica Yonatan, es algo así:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ref_producto,SUM(cuantia) Total FROM pedidos
      GROUP BY 1 HAVING Total < 5  
  ) c1 JOIN productos USING(ref_producto);
```

Si tienes cualquier duda, por favor pregúntame.

Comment: Gracias! Me sirvió... Que significa el c1?

Comment: Cuando utilizas subconsultas, les tienes que asignar obligatoriamente un alias. Cuando anidas unas cuantas las vas numerando, así no las confundes. La forma más sencilla de nombrarlas es con c1, c2, c3, ... pero puedes usar cualquier nombre que te aporte algo más de información. Me alegra haberte ayudado

Comment: Por favor, no las nombres como c1, c2, etc, tampoco como a, b, c. La mejor recomendación es darles un alias relevante que permita saber a que tabla o subconsulta pertenece una columna.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor es que te deshagas de las subconsultas y hagas las operaciones de forma directa. Será más fácil de entender al momento de revisar el código.

```
SELECT nombre_producto,
    SUM(cuantia) AS Total 
FROM pedidos ped
JOIN productos pro ON ped.ref_producto = pro.ref_producto
GROUP BY nombre_producto 
HAVING Total < 5;
```

[Aquí hay un artículo](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx) (en inglés) que explica un poco el uso de HAVING.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo, Luis: mucho más claro sin subconsultas. Si la tabla tuviera muchos registros, entonces ya sería recomendable realizar el agrupamiento con la mínima cantidad de datos. Es decir, antes del JOIN, y entonces sí que tendría sentido usar subconsultas.